# Create text input and assign a value based on array length and it's values on page load using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to create dynamic text inputs fields based on the array coming from the json. Number of input elements depends on the length of an array. The values of the input should be assigned with the values in the array. I'm creating input elements on the page load.

I have tried accessing the input elements after they have been loaded using setTimeout function but it didn't help as I have used class of the element to set the value, doing that copies all the input boxes with the last array value.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var addInput = '<input class="multi-val" value=""/>';
var str = 'test-1,test-2,test-3'; //string coming from json
var arr = [];
if(str.indexOf(',') != -1){
arr = str.split(','); //split the str and store it in the arr
if(Array.isArray(arr)){
$.each(arr,function(indx, output){
if(indx == 0) // first value of the array will always be assigned to already existing input box on the dom
$('.container').find('input.firstbox').val(output);
else {
$('.container').append(addInput);
$('.multi-val').val(output);
}
});
}
}
});
```

```css
.multi-val,.firstbox{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<input type="text" class="firstbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: *var str = 'test-1,test-2,test-3'; //string coming from json* <= **how?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to append the element and then change it.  The class selector is finding all of them, and changing the value of all of them.

Instead, make the input, set the value, and **then** append it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var addInput = '<input class="multi-val" value=""/>';
  var str = 'test-1,test-2,test-3'; //string coming from json
  var arr = [];
  if (str.indexOf(',') != -1) {
    arr = str.split(','); //split the str and store it in the arr
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
      $.each(arr, function(indx, output) {
        if (indx == 0) // first value of the array will always be assigned to already existing input box on the dom
          $('.container').find('input.firstbox').val(output);
        else {
        
        
        
        
          // CHANGED HERE
          var $newInput = $(addInput);
          $newInput.val(output);
          $('.container').append($newInput);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.multi-val,
.firstbox {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" class="firstbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Dang! I always gets there and miss small nuances which waste my time forever but anyhow everything is a lesson! Thank you Taplar :D